# Git with multiple users on other systems using setfacl?

Tags: linux, git, acl

I'm setting up a git environment where multiple developers will work with per project.
We have 1 server running git, and 2 separate servers, 1 live and 1 dev.

On dev, I created a group and added the needed users.
I've setfacl on multiple maps so that group can navigate through /home/ to the needed folders.
I've set a default setfacl on the git folder and below new coming folders/files?

```
setfacl -Rdm g:developers:rwX /home/username/domains/website/public_html/.git/ /home/username/domains/*/public_html/.git/*
```

As I understand it this would mean, the new files written after the previous code and by the actual owner of the website could be read/written into by the developer group, but it can't. I know this is a scenario you don't want and I might be completely incorrect, but the actual user has to pull, else I get write conflicts.

Am I doing something completely wrong? I'm also thinking about using the computer system's (private) key(?)  as a possibility to show who's committing the new files to git but I don't think I'm ready for that as I don't have the knowledge.

My knowledge isn't that high of Linux, don't laugh, I'm not asking for tutorials, just for clarification on my situation and usage of commands.